# Forward a 'non-existant' subdomain to a 'physical' subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain

How can I forward a 'non-existant' subdomain to a 'physical' subdomain?

I.e.: `api.website.com` -> `api.company.com`

Where the first is just a CNAME pointer and the last is a real subdomain with a root.

At `website.com` I have:

```
api CNAME api.company.com.
```

At `company.com` I have:

```
api.website.com CNAME api.company.com (also tried this with just API)
api.company.com A 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to create a subdomain to a root IP address, and then forward a subdomain from a different domain to this subdomain.

First you would create an `A` record for the `api.company.com` subdomain as demonstrated [here](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/record-entry/cname/) under "Example 1" (ignoring the FTP part; also note that `www` is considered a subdomain as well, just like `api`).

So in the DNS tables for `company.com` you'd create an `A` record for:

```
api.company.com A 1.2.3.4
```

This establishes an alias record for host `api.company.com` at IP address `1.2.3.4`

Next you'd create a CNAME to this external host as demonstrated [here](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/record-entry/cname/) under "Example 3". So in the DNS tables for `website.com` you'd create a CNAME record for:

```
api CNAME api.company.com.
```

This points `api.website.com` -> `api.company.com`

Then you'd need to wait 24-48 hours for these DNS changes to propagate to DNS servers throughout the Internet in order for these subdomains to resolve properly, so don't make any other changes during that time.

Comment: The first part is already there, because I created a legit subdomain for api.company.com. I had already added the CNAME record on website.com, so I guess I still have to wait for the changes to propogate? The weird part is.. when I go to api.website.com, it's white for a considerate amount of time before Chrome throws an error..

Comment: As indicated in your question, you didn't need to create a CNAME on `company.com` for `api.website.com` since that host should be managed in the DNS for the `website.com` domain. Also, this question and my answer are only addressing the DNS setup - you'll still have to make sure `api.company.com` is serving the content correctly, which `api.website.com` will also serve. Yes, you'll have to wait for the DNS to propagate once everything is setup correctly.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't work. You suggested: CNAME at original server and A at new server. I've done those both. But it seems like the new server should somehow know that it can accept the first domain, right?

Comment: That isn't necessary since you can forward a subdomain to any other subdomain, as demonstrated in the example links. However, as I wrote in my comment above, you'll have to do some configurations in your server to make sure the `api.company.com` subdomain is serving the content, and also not preventing `api.website.com` as a host.

Comment: BTW, is it necessary to have `api.website.com` -> `api.company.com` or can you just have `api.website.com` -> `1.2.3.4` since that's what `api.company.com` is pointed to anyway? In that case, you can just create an `A` record in the DNS for `website.com` for:  `api.website.com A 1.2.3.4`

Comment: Oh I made a mistake! The website.com site is behind cloudflare and I was adjusting the real DNS.. I'll check it again